# Deserializing XML to objects which has list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have following xml which I want to Deserialize to an object.

```
<result>
    <reporttype>2</reporttype>
    <items>
        <item>
            <sku>0B0005</sku>
            <style>0B0005.DAK.GREY</style>
            <reason>Barcode cannot be moved to different SKUs</reason>
        </item>
        <item>
            <sku>0B0006</sku>
            <style>0B0006.DAK.GREY</style>
            <reason>Barcode cannot be moved to different SKUs</reason>
        </item>
    </items>
</result>
```

But following code does not populate the item list, Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong here

```
string inputString = @"<result><reporttype>2</reporttype><items><item><sku>0B0005</sku><style>0B0005.DAK.GREY</style><reason>Barcode cannot be moved to different SKUs</reason></item><item><sku>0B0005</sku><style>0B0005.DAK.GREY</style><reason>Barcode cannot be moved to different SKUs</reason></item></items></result>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(inputString);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(doc.InnerXml);
Result resultingMessage = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);

public enum ReportType {
    [XmlEnum("0")]
    InternalErrorReport,
    [XmlEnum("1")]
    ErrorReport,
    [XmlEnum("2")]
    InternalSuccessReport
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "reporttype")]
    public ReportType reportType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "items")]
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    public string error { get; set; }

    public class Item {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sku")]
        string sku { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "style")]
        string style { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "reason")]
        string reason { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You haven't added the `XmlElement` attribute to the `Item` class, so the serializer doesn't know that `<item>` element is an `Item` class instance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I did try, but we cannot use [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")] for classes, it is only valid on property, field, ...

So we cannot use that

Comment: Change it to `[XmlArray("items")] and [XmlArrayItem("items")]`.

Comment: @Fabio That's what I meant to say, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable need to be public.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
            StringReader rdr = new StringReader(xml);
            Result resultingMessage = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);


        }
    }
    public enum ReportType
    {
        [XmlEnum("0")]
        InternalErrorReport,
        [XmlEnum("1")]
        ErrorReport,
        [XmlEnum("2")]
        InternalSuccessReport
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "reporttype")]
        public ReportType reportType { get; set; }
        public Items items { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }


    }
    [XmlRoot("items")]
    public class Items
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")]
        public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    }
    [XmlRoot("item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sku")]
        public string sku { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "style")]
        public string style { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "reason")]
        public string reason { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need create extra class for the collections - serializer perfectly will deserialize it to `List<T>`

Comment: Doing it your way would require adding a label indicating that item is an array.  I think this is confusing and explicitly indicating the classes is easier for novices to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can add two attributes for `items` property - to satisfy serialization

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result 
{
    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
}
```

Or just set type attribute(`XmlType`) for Item class.
Then will be enough to use only `XmlArray` attribute for `Result.items` property. Or not using any attribute at all because name of the property match with name of the element in xml.

```
[XmlType("item")]
public class Item 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sku")]
    public string sku { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "style")]
    public string style { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "reason")]
    public string reason { get; set; }
}
```

And of course **make properties public**

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Worked great for me.

Comment: this one worked for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As explained here you need to mark the list as XmlArray specifing also the XmlArrayItem: [Deserializing nested lists with XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006460/deserializing-nested-lists-with-xmlserializer)

So the code becomes:

```
        string inputString = @"<result><error>error test</error><reporttype>2</reporttype><items><item><sku>0B0005</sku><style>0B0005.DAK.GREY</style><reason>Barcode cannot be moved to different SKUs</reason></item><item><sku>0B0005</sku><style>0B0005.DAK.GREY</style><reason>Barcode cannot be moved to different SKUs</reason></item></items></result>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(inputString);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
        object resultingMessage = null;
        using (StringReader rdr = new StringReader(doc.InnerXml)) {
            resultingMessage = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
        }
```

and the classes:

```
public enum ReportType {
    [XmlEnum("0")]
    InternalErrorReport,
    [XmlEnum("1")]
    ErrorReport,
    [XmlEnum("2")]
    InternalSuccessReport
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "reporttype")]
    public ReportType reporttype { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "error")]
    public string error { get; set; }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "items\\item")]
    public class Item {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sku")]
        public string sku { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "style")]
        public string style { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "reason")]
        public string reason { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Please, note also that I encapsulated the string reader in a using block, in order to dispose the object once the read ends.

Answer (score 0):

items should be Xmlroot element and it contain XmlElement item,you have to tell when it Deserialize to object. try this :

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sku")]
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "style")]
    public string Style { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "reason")]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "items")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")]
    public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "reporttype")]
    public string Reporttype { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "items")]
    public Items Items { get; set; }
}
```